# Variable changing value for unknown reason?

Tags: java

I should probably know this but why is this changing `openPos[1]` to 0? I know its got to do with the `startPos[1] = 0` in the `findCloseCurlBracket()` method but why is it doing it it doesn't make sense.

```
int[] openPos = {1, 26};
    System.out.println(openPos[0]+", "+openPos[1]);
    int[] closePos = LuaTableParser.findCloseCurlBracket(stringList, openPos);
    System.out.println(openPos[0]+", "+openPos[1]);
```

findCloseCurlBracket() method:

```
public static int[] findCloseCurlBracket(List<String> text, int[] openPos) {
    int[] startPos = openPos;
    int counter = 1;
    for(int line = startPos[0]; line < text.size(); line++){
        for(int index = startPos[1]; index < text.get(line).length()-startPos[1]; index++){
            int[] curPos = {line, index};
            if(getStringListCharAt(text, curPos) == '{'){
                counter++;
            }else if(getStringListCharAt(text, curPos) == '}'){
                counter--;
            }
            if(counter == 0){
                startPos[1] = 5;
                return curPos;
            }
        }
        startPos[1] = 0;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `openPos` is a reference to (points to) an array. You're copying that reference (not the array, the reference to it) into `findCloseCurlBracket` as `openPos`. Then you're copying that reference into `startPos` so now the `openPos` variable, the `openPos` argument, and the `startPos` variable are all pointing to the same array in memory:

```
+-------------------+
| openPos variable  |--+
+-------------------+  |
                       |
+-------------------+  |     +-----------+
| openPos argument  |--+---->| the array |
+-------------------+  |     +-----------+
                       |     | 0: 1      |
+-------------------+  |     | 1: 26     |
| startPos variable |--+     +-----------+
+-------------------+
```

Then you do this:

```
startPos[1] = 5;
```

...which modifies the array:

```
+-------------------+
| openPos variable  |--+
+-------------------+  |
                       |
+-------------------+  |     +-----------+
| openPos argument  |--+---->| the array |
+-------------------+  |     +-----------+
                       |     | 0: 1      |
+-------------------+  |     | 1: 5      |
| startPos variable |--+     +-----------+
+-------------------+
```

Doesn't matter what reference you use, when you modify the state of what those references point to, you can see that change through all of them.

If you don't want to share the array, you'll need to make a copy of it, as [Bathsheba shows in her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34157554/157247) (+1):

```
int[] startPos = openPos.clone();
```

Comment: Ok so do I have to make a copy of each element of the array or how would I make a copy of the array?

Comment: I love the posh ASCII art. This is now *way* better than my answer. Plus one.

Answer (score 5):

`startPos` is referring to the same array as `openPos`: both things are *references* to an *array* of `int`s.

`int[] startPos = openPos;` does **not** take a deep copy of `openPos`.

Your writing `startPos[1] = 5;` is changing an element in the same array that `openPos` is referring to in the caller to `findCloseCurlBracket`.

One way to take a deep copy is to write `int[] startPos = openPos.clone();`.

Comment: Or `Arrays.copyOf(original, newLength);` -> `Arrays.copyOf(openPos, openPos.length);`

Comment: I much prefer the 'clone()' though. Easier to remember, for one.

Comment: Just throwing it out there to present some options. `Arrays.copyOf` and `Arrays.copyOfRange` can also copy a subset of the array. `clone()` will always copy the entire array. `copyOf` is a little more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning/copying the array.

```
int[] startPos = openPos;
```

You're playing with the same reference here.